# Postback model is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, postback

I changed my index view so that each row is wrapped in a form:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<LevEl.Models.Page>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Pages", item, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "itemForm_" + item.PageId }))
  { 
  <tr>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    </td>
    ...
    ... more fields
    ...
    <td>
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsPublished, new { onClick = "$(itemForm_" + item.PageId + ").submit();" })
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PageId }) | @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.PageId }) | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PageId })
    </td>
  </tr>
  }
}
```

Here's my controller:

**PagesController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View(db.Pages.Include(p => p.Language).ToList());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Page page)
{
  var method = Request.HttpMethod;

  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    if (page.PageContents.GroupBy(pc => pc.Language).Any(g => g.Count() > 1))
      return HttpNotFound("A page cannot have two translations in the same language.");

    db.Entry(page).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    ClearMenuKeys();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  return View(page);
}
```

When I switch the value in the check box and the controller is reached, `page` is null.
How can I pass the entire `page` object upon postback?

Comment: Can you add details of the `Page` class? Also, what is the type of model used for `Index` page?

Comment: It seems like your model is sth like IEnumerable<Page>, can you post model class and how model is bound to the view?

Comment: The page has multiple fields, many of which are boolean values and I want to be able to change them on the index page, without hitting 'save'. I want so that when the user changes a value in one of the rows, that row is immediately posted-back and the new value is saved.

Comment: In the index.cshtml you have code like "@model Namespace.Of.YourModel can you edit your post or paste this line in comment?

Comment: @Mariusz as i said, im talking about the index page, it's a collection of the model. question updated per request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like your HTML do not store values of the Page. `@Html.DisplayFor` only displays data  you have to set `@Html.HiddenFor` for that field too.

EDIT:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Title)
```

Comment: So bottom line, how do I make it work? BTW, unless this is all auto-generated for me, there are no `@Html.HiddenFor` fields that I'm aware of

Comment: No :( any ideas? Should I change the hidden value upon checkbox change, then trigger the postback? Is this the only option?

Comment: I don't thkink this is the case. Try ask question with generated html for that checkboxfor.